# Setup FTP in same IP but different ports?

Tags: iis, iis-7, ftp, windows-server-2008

Hi have an ip address that has an FTP already setup on it (port 21).

When I add another FTP site in IIS with the same IP and Port it says it cannot start because of a duplicate binding already in IIS.

So I'm curious if I bind the new FTP site with the same IP but will a different port work?

If so, which other port would work or be recommended for this, i suppose i would have to open access on Windows Firewall as well, so i just want to make sure it doesn't open the server up to any potential exploits by exposing the port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any port not already in use. Running `netstat` from an elevated command prompt will give you a list of ports in use. People usually use port `2121` or `8021` as an alternative port for FTP.

Although some ports are more frequently scanned by hackers, no port is intrinsically more insecure than others.